# Hacer POST con android studio desde un webview

Tags: android

Hola a todos tengo una simple aplicación que simplemente sera un cascaron, para un sistema de entrada y salida de empleados, lo tengo en la web y funciona bien en web, sin embargo al meterlo en un webview al momento de hacer login, no sale de mi pagina de login, supongo que es por que desde el webview no lo hace como en la web.

En mi aplicación solo tengo esto:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView WebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    final String url = "http://3.134.231.160/control/login.php";
    WebView.loadUrl(url);
    WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            WebView.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Y en la web (Aquí si funciona sin problemas hace login correcto) tengo esta parte:

```
if (isset($_POST['id_estilista'])){
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 38800);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["id_estilista"] = $_POST["id_estilista"];
    $_SESSION["nombre"] = $_POST["nombre"];
    header("Location: horas.php");
}else{
    session_start();
    session_unset(); 
    session_destroy(); 
}

function login(){
if($("#usuarios").val() == 0 || $("#password").val() == ""){
    SweetAlert("E", "Por favor llene todos los campos.");
}else{
    $("#content").addClass("force-dissapear");
    $("#loading").removeClass("force-dissapear");
    $.post("../api/v1/estilistas/login", {id_estilista: $("#usuarios").val(), password: $("#password").val()} , function(returnedData){
        $("#loading").addClass("force-dissapear");
        $("#content").removeClass("force-dissapear");
        if (returnedData["error"] == false) {
        $("#formlogin").append("<input type='hidden' name='id_estilista' value='" + returnedData["id_estilista"] + "' /><input type='hidden' name='nombre' value='" + returnedData["nombre"] + "' />");
        $("#formlogin").submit();
        } else SweetAlert("E", returnedData["message"]);
    });
}
```

}

Creo que eso es lo que no hace en el webview y por eso no me sale del login, hay algo que pueda hacer al respecto? Consulto por que no se realmente ni como buscar esto.

Espero su respuesta, gracias de antemano.

EDIT: En android si activo el permiso de internet

Comment: Por favor, pon [todo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) el código relacionado con el problema para que podamos ayudarte. Es imposible saber qué está fallando entre android y el servidor php sin ver más que esa línea.

Comment: He editado la pregunta

Comment: ¿Posterior al inicio de sesión, debería redireccionar a horas.php?

Comment: Asi es, asi lo hace desde la Web pero no en el webview

Comment: Entonces nadie sabe? :(

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que en la página que usas estas usando rutas relativas de los archivos, al cargar tu página dentro de un WebView trata de buscar los archivos dentro del proyecto lo cual causara problemas.

por ejemplo tienes en la página referencias como estas:

```
   <!-- BOOTSTRAP-->
   <script src="../admin/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <!-- STORAGE API-->
   <script src="../admin/vendor/js-storage/js.storage.js"></script>
```

deberías usar rutas absolutas:

```
   <!-- BOOTSTRAP-->
   <script src="http://3.134.231.160/admin/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <!-- STORAGE API-->
   <script src="http://3.134.231.160/admin/vendor/js-storage/js.storage.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola, probe poner la direccion directa en el $.post como sugeriste sin embargo, aun no funciona :(